# как подключить библиотеку к raspberry pi pico w

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico

Надо подключить библиотеку для дисплея https://github.com/russhughes/st7789_mpy к raspberry pi pico w. Пробовал подключить с помощью thonny ide. Но всегда выдает ошибку

> file:///C:/Users/noname/Downloads/st7789_mpy-master.zip does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
> Error: process returned with code 1

Comment: Это похоже на модуль для micropython (не для обычного python), который еще и скомпилировать похоже нужно. Не знаю как там thonny подключает, нужно читать readme и собирать по инструкции там.